Check information on a staking account in a smart contract
If I have a smart contract (written in Anchor), is it possible for me to read a staking account and discover information about it: delegated stake, the delegated vote account address, the stake authority and the stake withdraw authority?
The smart contract would perform some actions based on these values, but I don't know how to do this in Anchor.

It looks like anchor includes a StakeAccount type at https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/460a16171a715671f77ead5629391c0466366c08/spl/src/stake.rs#L131
Feel free to use it as a type in your program! Ie:
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct ProxyStake<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub stake: Account<'info, StakeAccount>,
    pub stake_program: Program<'info, Stake>,
... whatever else you need ...
}

